# (SOLVED) I need to use Excel Data Validation to validate the birth year, not less than 16 years old - using the functions YEAR and TODAY

Tags: excel, validation

UPDATE: I solved it:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzlFK.png)

I am working on a practice project, and am stuck on this. If I use a standard formula, I am sure I can do this, but I really need to use data validation in order to get a good grasp of this. I know it can be done, I'm just stumbling after repeated failed attempts. I am using the named range "Birth Year".

Here we go:

[image: Birth Year]

So, using "custom" and this doesn't work:

```
=YEAR(TODAY()-16)
```

Also, if I have "Today" as a named range in a list, and refer to that using "Date" in data validation, that also does not work

[image: Date Data Validation]

I am most likely going about this all wrong, but I had to start somewhere. Any ideas? Google has seriously let me down on this one...(SHOCK)

Comment: For a start =TODAY()-16 means today - 16 days

Comment: check out https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/conditional-formatting-to-highlight-if-its-over-a/10396ef1-c9a4-459d-b39a-2684b3459117

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-or-subtract-dates-b83768f5-f695-4311-98b1-757345f7e926

Comment: Use yearfrac() to get accuracy.